# declaration of a method with multiheritance

Tags: c++

Consider the following architecture:

```
class A { // abstract
    A();
    virtual void method() = 0;
}

class B {
    void method();
}

class C : public A, B {

};

int main () {
    A* a = new C(); // error
}
```

because `method()` is pure, it looks like that I still need to declare it in `C`, but I don't understand why because `B` already declares `method()`.

Why this can't work ? Doesn't `A` know that `C` also heritates from `B` ?

Aditional question, how can I make this work properly, without modifying `A`. For information, there could be lot of classes of type `C`.

Comment: No, `A` has no idea who inherits from it. And since you explicitly inherit 2 different classes that information is not shared between them

Comment: And `A* a = C();` is a syntax error to begin with. You probably meant `A* a = new C();` or similar

Comment: Also also, `method` in `B` and `C` are completely independent functions, so this cannot ever work (especially since one is `virtual` and the other is not)

Comment: `B` defines `method`, so `C` does. Isn't it ?

Comment: Just because 2 functions have the same name doesn't mean they are completely equivalent

Comment: (always) Add `override` to the functions you think override `virtual` functions. That'd be `void method() override;` in `B`. Since `B` doesn't inherit from _anything_ it becomes even more obvious that this can not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why this can't work ? Doesn't `A` know that `C` also heritates from `B`?

No, `A` has no clue and `B::method` does not override `A::method`. For that to happen, `B` would have to inherit from `A` either directly or indirectly.

> how can I make this work properly, without modifying A

You could let `B` inherit from `A` and then implement `method`:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class A { // abstract
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;

    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void method() override {}
};

class C : public B {
};

int main () {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<C>();
}
```

Comment: I forgot to tell, but I can't touch B neither. Maybe I will create a `D` class, that inherits from `A` and `B`, and C will inherit from `D`.

Comment: @tony_merguez Perhaps that's a workaround but it seems like something is a bit odd in the design. It would be easier to come up with the proper solution if you'd use some example classes and functions with more descriptive names than `A`, `B`, `C` and `method`.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I make this work properly, without modifying `A`

Maybe, what you want to do is this?

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class B
{
public:
    void method(){  std::cout << "B::method()" << std::endl;    }
};

class C : public A, B
{
public:
    virtual void method() override
    {
        std::cout << "C::method() calls B::method()" << std::endl;
        B::method();
    }
};
```

I don't know why you need the private inherit.
But if it is not necessary, I guess to be:

```cpp
class C : public A  //not inherit B
{
public:
    virtual void method() override
    {
        std::cout << "C::method() calls B::method()" << std::endl;
        m_B.method();
    }
private:
    B m_B;  //has B as member, instead.
};
```